# on and off image on home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview

I have one ImageView on a home screen widget , currently the image is static.
But I want to make that image flash, like ON and OFF automatically.

The image is keep flashing `green -> red -> green` like a siren.

> Initially Image is Red
>
> User Taps over Red Image , it stars flashing from Red to Green rapidly
>
> User Tags again it stops flashing and set to Red

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should take a peek at the ApiDemos.  I think `ApiDemos/src/com/exmaple/android/apis/graphics/ShapeDrawable1.java` demonstrates something close to what you want to do.

Comment: Well first thing is that i have two images green and red , so ShapeDrawable is not a solution , moreover i want it in a Home Screen Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `ViewFlipper` in XML.  To start/stop the flashing you can use the remoteview method `setViewVisibility()` to toggle between `redOnly` and `redAndGreen`.

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/redOnly"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/red" />

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/redAndGreen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateFirstView="false"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="700"
    android:measureAllChildren="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/green" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/red" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: if i use `setViewVisibility` will remove the widget from the Home Screen. wht i want is if i tap over a image it starts flashing `green to red` and tap again it stops to red

Comment: edited my answer to do what your asking.  you will have to use pendingIntents to capture the clicks.  i can add some code for that if you need.

Comment: ya i have added the pending clicks but when i click over viewflipper how would i start the animation ?

Comment: autostart="true" takes care of that.  when the viewflipper goes from GONE to VISIBILE it will automatically start flipping.

Comment: yeah i got it now , but is there a way to call `stopFlipping` using `remoteView.setInt` or some other function ?